# Join over multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, select

I am developing a web application about Pokémon characters, which should show the following data: **Name, Image, Category, Type, Skills (up to 3) and Weaknesses (up to 3)**.

The model and tables I'm working on is the following:

[image: Relational Model]

**Note about tables:**
Type=Tipo, Category= Categoria, Weaknesses=Debilidad, Skill=Habilidad, PokemonType=PokemonTipo, PokemonWeaknesses=PokemonDebilidad, PokemonSkill= PokemonHabilidad

The "PokemonTipo", "PokemonDebilidad", and "PokemonHabilidad" tables keep "many-to-many" records of Types, Weaknesses, and Abilities for each Pokemon.

The Select I am using is this.

```
SELECT po.idPokemon, po.nombre AS 'Pokemon', po.imagen, cat.nombre AS 'Categoria', ti.nombre 
AS 'Tipo',
ha.nombre AS 'Habilidad', de.nombre AS 'Debilidad'
FROM Pokemon po 
INNER JOIN Categoria cat
ON po.idCategoria = cat.idCategoria
INNER JOIN PokemonTipo pt
ON po.idPokemon = pt.idPokemon
INNER JOIN Tipo ti
ON ti.idTipo = pt.idTipo
INNER JOIN PokemonHabilidad ph
ON po.idPokemon = ph.idPokemon
INNER JOIN Habilidad ha
ON ha.idHabilidad = ph.idHabilidad
INNER JOIN PokemonDebilidad pd
ON po.idPokemon = pd.idPokemon
INNER JOIN Debilidad de
ON de.idDebilidad = pd.idDebilidad
GROUP BY po.idPokemon
ORDER BY po.idPokemon
```

As can be seen in the image, with the Select I use, **I only get one Skill (Habilidad) and one Weakness (Debilidad) for each Pokémon**.

[image: Join]

The problem that I have not been able to solve is: **how to obtain and separate the Skill (Habilidad) and Weakness (Debilidad) of each Pokémon in different columns with the same Select.**

For each Pokémon I must have the following fields:

**Name, Image, Category, Type, Skill 1, Skill 2, Skill 3, Weakness 1, Weakness 2, Weakness 3**

The database script, in case you want to do tests, can be obtained at this link. https://github.com/jcesarux/pokebase/blob/master/pokebase.sql

I would appreciate a different point of view on how to approach the problem.

Grettings and thank you for the support.!!

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT columname)` for the attributes with multiple values.

Comment: With a focus on the 'M' component of MCRE, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not a valid aggregation query to start with, because the `select` and `group by` clause are not consistent. Unfortunately, unlike most other databases, MySQL happily compiles and runs it, and you actually get just one (any) skill and weakness per pokemon.

You can do what you want with `row_number()` and conditional aggregation. The idea is to rank the skills and weeknesses of each pokemon in subqueries, and then pivot the resultset in the outer query.

```
SELECT po.idPokemon, 
    po.nombre AS Pokemon, 
    po.imagen, 
    cat.nombre AS Categoria, 
    ti.nombre AS Tipo,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ha.rn = 1 THEN ha.nombre END) AS Habilidad1, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ha.rn = 2 THEN ha.nombre END) AS Habilidad2, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ha.rn = 3 THEN ha.nombre END) AS Habilidad3, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN de.rn = 1 THEN de.nombre END) AS Debilidad1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN de.rn = 2 THEN de.nombre END) AS Debilidad2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN de.rn = 3 THEN de.nombre END) AS Debilidad3
FROM Pokemon po 
INNER JOIN Categoria cat ON po.idCategoria = cat.idCategoria
INNER JOIN PokemonTipo pt ON po.idPokemon = pt.idPokemon
INNER JOIN Tipo ti ON ti.idTipo = pt.idTipo
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ph.idPokemon, ha.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ph.idPokemon ORDER BY ph.idHabilidad) rn
    FROM PokemonHabilidad ph 
    INNER JOIN Habilidad ha ON ha.idHabilidad = ph.idHabilidad
) ha ON ha.idPokemon = po.idPokemon
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pd.idPokemon, de.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pd.idPokemon ORDER BY de.idHabilidad) rn
    FROM PokemonDebilidad pd 
    INNER JOIN Debilidad de ON de.idDebilidad = pd.idDebilidad
) de ON ON de.idPokemon = po.idPokemon
GROUP BY po.idPokemon, cat.idCategoria, ti.idTipo
ORDER BY po.idPokemon
```

Note that window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only.